# How To Parse Key Value of Nested Dictionary With A List?

Tags: python, json, parsing, dictionary

I would like to parse the 'amount' from this JSON string...

```
json_data = {
    u'orderNumber': u'135490818',
    u'resultingTrades': [
        {
            u'tradeID': u'91846',
            u'rate': u'0.00003530',
            u'amount': u'10', u'date':
            u'2015-04-09 13:47:29',
            u'total': u'0.000353',
            u'type': u'buy'
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying:

```
json_data['orderNumber']['resultingTrades']['tradeID']['amount']
```

I'm getting the error: `Error: string indices must be integers`

I believe the error is because the dictionary is nested with a list.

What is the correct way to parse 'amount'?

Answer (score 4):

Just do this

```
json_data['resultingTrades'][0]['amount']
```

When you are doing this

```
json_data['orderNumber']['resultingTrades']['tradeID']['amount']
```

`json_data['orderNumber']` returns '135490818' which is a string and then the above statement becomes

```
'135490818'['resultingTrades']['tradeID']['amount']
```

Now you are trying to index a string using a string which is not allowed as string python can only be accessed using integers.

Answer (score 2):

*"string indices must be integers"* implies that you are using the JSON string as it is. To access the data, you first have to parse the string into a Python data container, a dictionary in this case:

```
import json
json_data = 'json_data = { u"orderNumber": u"135490818", u"resultingTrades": [ { u"tradeID": u"91846", u"rate": u"0.00003530", u"amount": u"10", u"date": u"2015-04-09 13:47:29", u"total": u"0.000353", u"type": u"buy" } ] }'

python_data  = json.loads(json_data)
```

`json.loads()` is for *"load string"*, so your JSON string is being parsed.

Now you can access your amount [as avinash pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29545139/1525423):

```
python_data['resultingTrades'][0]['amount']
```